# Capturing React Refs via Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have the following JSX:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Register extends Component {
    handleSubmit(){
        console.log("hey!")
    }

    setHandles(c){
        //This never executes.
        console.log("foo");
    }    

    render() {
        return (
<form className='form-horizontal' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />        
    <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="Email" className="col-md-2 control-label">User Name</label>
        <div className="col-md-10">
            //********************************
            //**** USING SETHANDLES HERE *****
            //********************************
            <input type="email" className="form-control" ref="{this.setHandles}" />
            <span className="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="Password" className="col-md-2 control-label">Password</label>
        <div className="col-md-10">
            //********************************
            //**** USING SETHANDLES HERE *****
            //********************************
            <input type="password" className="form-control" ref="{this.setHandles}" />
            <span className="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
...
```

My `setHandles` function never executes.  Why?

My intent is to given each `input` the attribute `ref="{this.setHandles}"` so that the `setHandles` callback can register each corresponding DOM element.  Later, when I am ready to post the form, I can loop through the array of DOM elements to grab the corresponding input values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not calling your function because you are passing a String, [remove the quote marks](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/601/), `ref={this.setHandles}`.

However, a better way to achieve what you want would be to assign an onChange event to every input in order to store the values in your state.

Something like this

```
constructor(props){
   this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
   this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
}
onSubmit(){
   console.log(this.state); // You got your input values here
}
onChange(e){
    this.setState({[e.target.name] : e.target.value});
}
render(){
   return <div><form> 
    <input type="text" name="mail" className="form-control"
    onChange={this.onChange} />
    <input type="text" name="password"
    className="form-control" ref={this.setHandles} onChange={this.onChange} />
    <button onClick={this.onSubmit}>Submit</button>
   </form></div>
}
```

[full working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/599/)

Comment: Remove quotes.  Sigh.  This is what I get for programming when tired.  Also, thanks much for the generic onChange idea.

Answer (score 0):

The `setHandles` function is never running because it has no reason to; it's not called, and functions in JSX without `()` at the end don't run unless they're asked to.

I would suggest to throw your desired function into the `componentDidMount()` React method, so it would look like this:

```
class Register extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // Do the thing
  }

  render() {
    ... 
  }
}
```

Here's React's doc on it: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount

Comment: Ref is a special handler in react that is used to fetch a sub component DOM element when this sub component is rendered. See [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html).